# EF Core Generic Entity Base and Recursive Entity

Tags: c#, data-structures, entity-framework-core

In a project where I'm using **ef core configured with a lazy loading proxy**, I want to handle two types of `Message` classes that **recurs themselves**.

Should I create a structure like the one established with the `MessageType` Enum and **store both Message types in a single Table-Entity**, or is the current structure better?

Also, **in terms of performance and best practice**, do I need to **create a new Table-Entity for Replies**, or is the current structure okay?

Base Message Class

```
public abstract class MessageBase<TMessage> : ModifiableEntityBase, IMessage
        where TMessage : class, IMessage
    {
        protected MessageBase(Guid id, Guid createdById, MessageType type) : base(id, createdById)
            => Type = type;

        public MessageType Type { get; private init; }
        public string? VideoPath { get; private init; }
        public string? ImagePath { get; private init; }
        public string? Text { get; private init; }

        public Guid? ParentId { get; protected init; }
        public virtual TMessage? Parent { get; protected init; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<TMessage> Replies { get; set; } = default!;

        public virtual IEnumerable<AppUser> LikedUsers { get; protected set; } = default!;

        public static MessageBase<TMessage> CreateVideoMessage(Guid id, Guid createdById, string videoPath,
            string? text = null)
            => new(id, createdById, MessageType.Video)
            {
                VideoPath = videoPath,
                Text = text
            };

        public static MessageBase<TMessage> CreateImageMessage(Guid id, Guid createdById, string imagePath,
            string? text = null)
            => new(id, createdById, MessageType.Image)
            {
                ImagePath = imagePath,
                Text = text
            };
            
        public static MessageBase<TMessage> CreateSoundMessage(Guid id, Guid createdById, string soundPath,
            string? text = null)
            => new(id, createdById, MessageType.Sound)
            {
                SoundPath = soundPath,
                Text = text
            };

        public static MessageBase<TMessage> CreateTextMessage(Guid id, Guid createdById, string text)
            => new(id, createdById, MessageType.Text)
            {
                Text = text
            };
    }
```

Sub Message Classes

```
public sealed class DirectMessage : MessageBase<DirectMessage>
    {
        public DirectMessage(Guid id, Guid createdById, MessageType type) : base(id, createdById, type)
        {
        }
    }
    
    public class GroupMessage : MessageBase<GroupMessage>
    {
        public GroupMessage(Guid id, Guid createdById, Guid groupId, MessageType type) : base(id, createdById, type)
            => GroupId = groupId;

        public Guid GroupId { get; init; }
        public virtual Group Group { get; private set; } = default!;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just one `Path` property? The `MessageType` defines what it's for (or if should have a value).

Comment: You'll have to consider the kinds of queries that you'll need to perform against your table, and the resulting SQL performance. Ask yourself questions like "Will there be self-joins?" And "will insertions/updates/deletes depend on other data in the same table?" Another thing to consider is that your data structure currently allows infinite reply chains (reply to a reply to a reply....) Which you may restrict in application code, but whose fetching can be very expensive, so you may want to perform mitigations in app code, the db, or both

Comment: @GertArnold I thought it would be more performant to separate the data into separate tables, but it got too complicated. As you suggested, it might be simpler to store it in a single Table-Entity with the path property.

Comment: @AndyG I decided to create a new non-recursive Entity named `Reply` and added these properties: `Message RepliedMessage`, `AppUser Recipient`, `Message Message`.
And added a boolean `IsReply` Property to `Message` class.

In this way, a main message will have only one layer of replies, and users will be able to tag each other in that response layer. I think this is a more convenient and efficient method.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing improper about a tree structure. I do think the enum is overkill.

Comment: @AluanHaddad The tree structure seemed very complicated in terms of manageability, I struggled a lot with generic structures.
The enum structure made it more manageable.
I guess I didn't implement the tree structure properly.

Comment: Well, if what you're trying to describe is a tree, it makes sense to have a table with a single nullable parent referencing that same table. Sometimes it just makes sense